# Duvida para retornar uma consulta

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Tenho o seguinte problema, no sql server eu tenho uma tabela de contratos e uma de clientes onde retorna da seguinte forma:

[image: Tabela]

Na condição where preciso pegar apenas o ultimo id criado do contrato de cada cliente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver seria utilizando a função SQL [`max`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) com auxilio da função [`group by`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) como uma subquery da cláusula [`IN`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Segue um exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM contrato WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(c.id) FROM contrato c GROUP BY c.cliente);
```

### Explicando o código

A função `max` Retorna o valor máximo na expressão (que neste caso é a coluna `id`)

O `group by` é uma cláusula da instrução SELECT que divide o resultado da consulta em grupos de linhas, normalmente, com a finalidade de executar uma ou mais agregações em cada grupo.

O operador lógico `IN` determina se um valor especificado corresponde a qualquer valor em uma sub-consulta ou uma lista.

Desta forma estamos primeiro agrupando os maiores valores da coluna (id_contratos) agrupados pelo valor da coluna `cliente`.

Ao ter os `id's` desejados em uma lista, agora basta exibir todos os valores daquelas linhas. Para isso usamos o `select *` externo.